# C#- Add/ display an instance of an application inside a <TabItem> of another application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a fully functioning C# WPF application, which allows users to view PDF files from inside the application (File -> Load -> Select PDF).

I am also working on another C# WPF application, which has several different features, and I am displaying each of the features to the user on a separate tab using a `<TabControl>`

I would like to add the PDF Viewer capability to this second application, inside a new tab- I know that I could just copy over the source for the PDF Viewer manually into a new `<TabItem>` inside my second application, but what I am wondering is if there is a 'tidier' way of doing this, by creating an instance of my PDF Viewer application, and displaying that inside a new tab in my second application?

Is it possible to create an instance of one application from inside another? How would I do this if so?

Comment: It depends on how modular is your first application. If your first application followed MVVM principles you can re-use almost all of it

Comment: Sorry- I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: the PDF viewer application did it just have one window and the code behind had the logic for fetching all the binding variables ?

Comment: Yes, the PDF viewer just had the one window- it was very basic- a window with a 'File' menu, from which you could 'Load' a document (using the `OpenFileDialog`), and it then displayed the selected PDF in a `PDFPanel` that I had added using the `MoonPdf` library. The code behind contained all of the methods/ implementation for the menu and loading a file.

Comment: There was one other class (`PdfViewer`), which inherited from `UserControl`, had one `string` variable to hold the filepath, and its constructor just called `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Typically you would move all the code from code behind to a view model ( a class) and use commands and data binding to communicate to view ( the xaml) that way you can re-use your view model. if pdf viewer is a user control derived class you can  move the control into a Class Library project and reference the class library from the consuming applications

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a WPF user control library project(WpfControlLibrary1) , Move all of your PDF user code to that project and use the user control (UserControl1) in both projects either in code 
as

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Content = new WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1();
    }
}
```

or in XAML you can use

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCustomControlLibrary1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <lib:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```